# Excel formular issue

Tags: excel

Want to try and do this within excel;

`If a cell (d2) = JOHN`

```
Then Cell (f2) = (e2*0.16)
```

So basically trying to say if the name is a name then the amount in cell `f` is * by `0.16p`

Comment: Otherwise, what is the value?

Comment: You need to place the `IF` formula on the cells that is being modified (with other words, in the cells of column F)

Answer (score 0):

`IF` function syntax,

`IF(logical_test , [value_if_true] , [value_if_false])`

So your formula should be, (please see image)

```
=IF(D1="John",E1*0.16,"Not John")
```

[image]

You can change the "Not John" per your needs.